# Missing data points in PSTricks plot

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=0.1,yunit=0.002}
\savedata{\data}[{1924,300},{1928,510},{1932,310},{1936,880},{1948,700},
{1952,730},{1956,820},{1960,660},{1964,1100},{1968,1160},
{1972,1220},{1976,1130},{1980,1070},{1984,1300},{1988,1430},
{1992,1810},{1994,1750},{1998,2176},{2002,2399}]
\begin{pspicture}(-9,-240)(102,2950)
  \psaxes[
    dx=10,
    dy=500,
    labels=none,
    ticklinestyle=dotted,
    tickwidth=0.5pt,
    xticksize=0 2500,
    yticksize=0 90
  ]{->}(0,0)(0,0)(95,2750)[Year,0][Participants,90]
  \psaxes[
    Ox=1920,
    Dx=10,
    Dy=500
  ](0,0)(0,0)(95,2750)
  % Data (NOT working)
  \dataplot[
    plotstyle=dots,
    dotstyle=o,
    fillcolor=red
  ]{\data}
  % Years 1924--1976
  \psplot[
    linecolor=blue,
    algebraic
  ]{4}{56}{15.6394*x+303.3}% Regression with Mathematica
  % Years 1980--2002
  \psplot[
    linecolor=blue,
    algebraic
  ]{60}{82}{60.793*x-2619.99}% Regression with Mathematica
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

How do I show the data in the plot?

I was thinking of using `\pstScalePoints` to scale the data on the x-axis but this only works with `listplot` according to the manual.

P.S. I will really like *not* to use `psgraph`; I'm not a big fan of the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\savedata{\data}[{1924,300},{1928,510},{1932,310},{1936,880},{1948,700},
{1952,730},{1956,820},{1960,660},{1964,1100},{1968,1160},
{1972,1220},{1976,1130},{1980,1070},{1984,1300},{1988,1430},
{1992,1810},{1994,1750},{1998,2176},{2002,2399}]
\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0pt,griddots=5,subgriddiv=0}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-0.5,-0.5)(9.49,5.49)
  \psaxes[Ox=1920,Dx=10,dx=1,Dy=500,dy=1]{->}(0,0)(9.4,5.4)[Year,0][Participants,90]
  \pstScalePoints(1,1){ 1920 sub 10 div}{ 500 div }
  \listplot[plotstyle=dots,dotstyle=*,linecolor=red]{\data}
  % Years 1924--1976
  \psplot[linecolor=blue,algebraic]{0.4}{5.6}{(15.6394*x*10+303.3)/500}% Regression with Mathematica
  % Years 1980--2002
\psplot[linecolor=blue,algebraic]{6}{8.2}{(60.793*x*10-2619.99)/500}% Regression with Mathematica
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect (as usual), Herbert!